# How to print only a specific part of a file

Tags: python, telegram, telepot

so i have a list of names like:

```
XX1
XX2
XX3
XZ1
XZ2
```

divided by brands , like:

```
Atlas

    XX1
    XX2
    XX3

Tediore

    XZ1
    XZ2
```

after this I would like to print only the specific weapon of the requested brand chosen by the user:

```
elif text.startswith('/weapon'):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard =[[InlineKeyboardButton(text='Atlas', callback_data='Atlas')],
                                                      [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Tediore', callback_data='tediore')],
                                                      [InlineKeyboardButton(text='DAHL', callback_data='DAHL')],])
bot.sendMessage(msg_data['chat_id'],"Select the brand ?",reply_markup = keyboard )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are shooting for but you could use a nested dictionary strategy with the brand being keys for the first level and tags like 'weapon' being the second level. e.g.

```
myBrands={'brand1':{'weapon':brandOneWeapon}}
```

So that when you call myBrands you can use the keys to obtain only what you want.

```
currentWeapon=myBrands['brand1']['weapon']
print(currentWeapon)
```